# jQuery- .css() not working for an input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

This should be a really simple problem, but I can't quite figure out what I am doing wrong.  I am trying to access the CSS property 'border-bottom' like this:

```
var temp = $('#divName').css('border-bottom');
```

Unfortunately, after this, temp contains the string `""`

Does anyone know why this is not working or what I should do differently to make it function?  Thanks.

Comment: Does `#divName` already contain the `border-bottom` property?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The styles have to be more specific. Since `border-bottom` is a short-property for other properties (similar to `background`, to name a common one), the property has to be explicitly given.

```
var elem = $('#divName');
var border_width = elem.css('border-bottom-width');
var border_color = elem.css('border-bottom-color');
var border_style = elem.css('border-bottom-style');
var border_bottom = border_width + " " + border_color + " " + border_style;
```

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6wRj4/**
See also: [MDN: `border-bottom` short-hand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/border-bottom).

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that this is *not* considered a bug in jQuery. jQuery reports the CSS attributes exactly as the browser returns them, and different browsers sometimes return different answers for the same HTML document.

Comment: In fact, the `window.computedStyle()` and `element.currentStyle[]` (IE) methods are used. Some values are modified by jQuery, to show the same result across different browsers.

Comment: Ahh.  Now that makes a lot of sense.  I saw something like this in the Jquery docs, but didn't put 2 and 2 together.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Check to ensure that $('#divName') does select a single element. You can use array syntax on a jquery object to get back the underlying DOM object. You should also check (for example, using Firebug) to make sure that the DOM element you're looking at does have the style that you're looking for.

If both of those things are working correctly, you might try using the more granular border properties... border-bottom-style, border-bottom-width, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `document.getElementById("divName").style.borderBottom;`.